# How to simplify multiple addition and convolution operations into one convolution kernel

Tags: image-processing, discrete-signals, fourier-transform, convolution

I need to perform such a conversion to simplify my image processing problem (sharpening, in green are the knowns, in red the unknowns):

\begin{align}
y(n,m) &= \color{green}{x(n,m)} * \left[ \color{red}{f_1(n,m) + f_2(n,m)} + \color{green}{f_3(n,m)}\right]\\
&= \color{green}{x(n,m) + kx(n,m) - x(n,m) * kg(n,m)}
\end{align}

Notice that the convolution done here is two-dimensional. And I know that $$ f_3  = -kg ;$$
where $k$ is a constant. However, I could not find $f_1$ and $f_2$, I tried to use convolution Theorem to switch to FT then going back to time/spatial-domain but it did not  obtain the same result. 
Here is a better explanation for the requested problem: 
[image]
To perform such a process to an input image, instead of performing the three separated steps shown in the top figure, I need to find such a kernel; let's call f where 
$$
f = f_1 + f_2 + f_3
$$
and then convolve it directly with the input image to find the same output image described in the block diagram figure. 
Any help/idea?

Comment: Sorry, it's not quite clear what your *given* things are, and what things you are looking for. Could you state that in your question?

Comment: I tried to describe it better now, my given things are x(n,m), k, and g(n,m). Things I want to find are  f1,f2, and f3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's rearrange
\begin{align}
x(n,m) * \left[ f_1(n,m) + f_2(n,m) + f_3(n,m)\right]
&= x(n,m) + kx(n,m) - x(n,m) * kg(n,m)\\
x(n,m) * \left[ f_1(n,m) + f_2(n,m) \right]
&= x(n,m) + kx(n,m)\\
&=(1+k)x(n,m)
\end{align}
It directly follows from the linearity of convolution that $f_1+f_2=(1+k)\delta_{n,m}^{(N \times M)}$, where $\delta^{(N\times M)}$ is the Kronecker delta of the same size as your input $x$, i.e. an all-zero matrix with a 1 in the $0,0$ element; the neutral element for 2D-convolution.

So, it's possible to calculate what the sum of $f_1 + f_2$ is, but not the individual $f_1$ and $f_2$; $f_1= \delta^{(N\times M)}, f_2 = k\delta^{(N\times M)}$ is as correct as
$f_1=\begin{pmatrix}1234 & 1 & \cdots &1\\0 & 0 & \cdots &0\\0 & 0 & \cdots &0\\\end{pmatrix},f_2=\begin{pmatrix}-1233+k & -1 & \cdots &-1\\0 & 0 & \cdots &0\\0 & 0 & \cdots &0\\\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that this solution works fine. However, there is a slight difference between the histograms of output images obtained from two methods. I think theoretically they should match each other, but may be Python calculations lead to some precision loss. Moreover, I think that delta matrix should the size of G not X since the size of G < X we need a kernel of the same size as the Gaussian Filter size is.